# webpack windows invalid character

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babeljs

I am creating a simple react project using webpack npm and babel.
I am able to install all the dependencies using npm.
when I try to start the webpack-dev-server, it errors out.
Can someone please suggest a way out.
I use the command npm run dev to start, defined in the package.json

[image]

here is my webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var config = {
  entry: "D:\github\UI\ReactWebpackBabel\app\index.jsx",
  output: {
    path: "D:\github\UI\ReactWebpackBabel\build",
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/':
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
    port: 3333
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      include: "D:\github\UI\ReactWebpackBabel\app\index.jsx",
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        presets: ['babel-preset-es2015', 'react']
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "reactwebpackbabel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "D:\\github\\UI\\ReactWebpackBabel\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js --config D:\\github\\UI\\ReactWebpackBabel\\code\\ReactWebpackBabel\\webpack.confg.js",
    "build": "webpack --config D:\\github\\UI\\ReactWebpackBabel\\code\\ReactWebpackBabel\\webpack.confg.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please also post the relevant part e.g. your `webpack-dev-server.js` where the error does appear? Actually there must be an error at char 1 at the webpack file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use webpack-dev-server.cmd not *.js file. Especially on Windows ;)
It stays here -> `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`.
It should also run without full path. Npm script will locate it in node_modules.
Check out getting started: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server